# main thread closes after running terminal command from controller

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, gnome-terminal

```
def create
    # exec('python')
    Thread.new do
        puts"exec"
        exec('python3.7 -c "print(\"Ran a new command in thread\")"')
    end

    render json: {"message": "Successfully added image", "status": "200"}, status: :ok
end
```

after this code runs the server closes

Can anyone help me understand what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I should use `system` instead of `exec` to run my command.

`system` runs the command in a subshell.\

so now the code becomes

```
system 'python3.7 -c "print(\"Ran a new command in thread\")"'
```